# How to recover file from ransomware with "[3442516480@qq.com].pdf" in each file

Tags: malware, antivirus, virus

Which steps should I do to recover my files which are affected by ransomware.

Each html file is changed to byte-code and renamed as `[3442516480@qq.com].pdf` at last.

Please share you experience on this.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

First you should know what type of ransomware you are infected with. In your case https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/15698-pdf-ransomware this might help you.

Also, You should give a try to some free reamsomware decryptor tools such as STOP Decryptor,Rakhni Decryptor provided by some antivirus companies for free.

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/windows/ransomware-decryptors/

If you get the variant of the ransomware you are infected with you can try a specific tool on your files if that helps you.